# Postgresql - Simpler way to count occurrences of a boolean condition

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to count the total number of rows returned, additionally I want to count the number of occurrences of a boolean condition. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), COUNT(field > 42)
FROM some_table
WHERE some_other_conditions
```

However the query above doesn't work because the boolean condition `field > 42` evaluates to false, which is still counted. I can rewrite the query to this, which does work:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), COUNT(CASE WHEN field > 42 THEN true END)
FROM some_table
WHERE some_other_conditions
```

What I am doing here is leveraging the missing `ELSE` clause of the `CASE` to default to a `NULL` value - which isn't counted.
Note: The queries above are just examples, the real query has additional fields on the select, joins, group by and order by clauses.

The `COUNT(CASE ...` syntax is rather convoluted, is there a more concise way to express the same concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM((field > 42)::int)
FROM some_table
WHERE some_other_conditions
```

or more appropriately a `FILTER`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE field > 42)
FROM some_table
WHERE some_other_conditions
```